# Specific word for the point of the terrestrial surface "under" a star or other object in the sky

Tags: coordinate

The title says it : I am looking for the word to use for a point, located on Earth surface (maybe an hypothetical perfectly spherical Earth), that has the same coordinates as a specific star, and therefore can be considered to be "under" the star in layman's terms.

Comment: But such a position can only be transient, so there is no such definition involving the coordinates being the same?

Comment: What is wrong with the word "under" or "beneath" ?  You do need to specify time to relate that to a location on the Earth.

Comment: "Subsolar point" and "sublunar point" are used for sun and moon.  Not sure I've ever heard of a more general term used for other objects.

Comment: Orthogonal projection?

Comment: @BowlofRed You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Meet me at the **subsirius** point at 130am UT on July 12th 2018. This describe a single point and time on the earth's surface. You could use any other star or planet.

Comment: And remember your cozzie, that's right in the middle of the Pacific (16*44' S 176* W)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Nothing against the word "under". The vocabulary of astronomy is rich and accurate, I just thought a specific word might have existed for that concept.

Comment: The term [ground track](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_track) is sometimes used for a spacecraft, and it could be applied to a natural body as well (as in those solar eclipse or occultation ground path plots). Of course it is the set of sub-object points for all times within a specified range, rather than at a single moment in time. Sometimes when looking for a tough word, English stackexchange can be helpful, but they are sticklers for prior research - check other successful [word-request tagged](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) first.

Answer (score 1):

Positions are usually given relative to the observer, not relative to the object. So instead of saying "I am under the star X", you would say "star X is overhead". The word for an object directly overhead is zenith: "the star X is at the zenith".

Comment: Related, but I don't think the appropriate answer is the term *Nadir*. This is the point directly below the observer. If the object is directly overhead, at the observer's Zenith, then the point on the Earth under the object is the observers Nadir.

Answer (score 1):

The point on the earth where the sun is directly overhead is commonly called the [subsolar point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsolar_point).  I've also heard sublunar point which would be the point corresponding to the moon.

I'm not aware of any more general term for this point relating to any other astronomical objects.

Comment: I think "sub-stellar" point would be understood.